# Podman build $XDG_RUNTIME_DIR no space left on device

Tags: podman

I'm having a hard time changing the directory where podman commits containers (during image build), my computer XDG_RUNTIME_DIR is a tmpfs of 1GiB size, which fails for large commits.
I set runroot = "/var/tmp" in ~/.config/containers/storage.conf, removed ~/.local/share/containers and podman --log-level=debug info correctly display

```
DEBU[0000] Using run root /var/tmp
DEBU[0000] Using tmp dir /run/user/1000/libpod/tmp
```

But when building a dockerfile I keep getting this error

```
error copying layers and metadata for container "9934f25f0f10548bcab123ef6d5bc8844a670f89d242f8b7cc658b41cf38810f": writing blob: storing blob to file "/run/user/1000/storage565735543/1": write /run/user/1000/storage565735543/1: no space left on device
```

How can I make podman not write in $XDG_RUNTIME_DIR?

I also created an issue on podman github https://github.com/containers/podman/issues/16227

Comment: Have you tried using __--tmpdir__? That option should be placed between `podman` and `run`, in other words `podman --tmpdir=/some/path run ...`. See https://docs.podman.io/en/latest/markdown/podman.1.html#tmpdir

Comment: That's seems to be it, in the logs:
`DEBU[0000] Overriding tmp dir "/var/tmp" with "/run/user/1000/libpod/tmp" from database`
instead of `DEBU[0000] Using tmp dir /run/user/1000/libpod/tmp` previously

Now got to figure out how to change value in database, and if there is a conf to set in dotfile

Comment: Even when removing `~/.local/share/containers` and running first podman command with `--tmpdir=/some/path` debug logs says its using /run/user/1000. I'm stuck

Answer (score 0):

I have been able to set the wanted path using the following commands

```
rm -r ~/.local/share/containers
export XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/var/tmp
podman build x
```

Subsequent podman commands will use value in 'database' an not `$XDG_RUNTIME_DIR`
Also podman seems to always use the `$TMPDIR` env var so you might need to change that each time you run podman